# In Slurm, is there a quick command to determine the total number of jobs (pending and active) at a given moment?

Tags: linux, bash, slurm

In slurm, calling the command `squeue -u <username>` will list all the jobs that are pending or active for a given user. I am wondering if there was a quick way to tally them all so that I know how many outstanding jobs there are, including pending and actively running jobs. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you just want to summarize the output of `squeue`, how about:

```
squeue -u <username> | awk '
BEGIN {
    abbrev["R"]="(Running)"
    abbrev["PD"]="(Pending)"
    abbrev["CG"]="(Completing)"
    abbrev["F"]="(Failed)"
}
NR>1 {a[$5]++}
END {
    for (i in a) {
        printf "%-2s %-12s %d\n", i, abbrev[i], a[i]
    }
}'
```

which yields something like:

```
R  (Running)    1
PD (Pending)    4
```

**Explanations:**

- The `job state` is assumed to be in the 5th field according to the default format of `squeue`.
- Then the script counts the appearance of each job state code except for the 1st line which includes the header.
- Finally it reports the count of each job state code.

In order to make it handy, add the following lines to your `.bash_aliases` or `.bashrc` (the filename may depend on the system):

```
function summary() {
    squeue "$@" | awk '
    BEGIN {
        abbrev["R"]="(Running)"
        abbrev["PD"]="(Pending)"
        abbrev["CG"]="(Completing)"
        abbrev["F"]="(Failed)"
    }
    NR>1 {a[$5]++}
    END {
        for (i in a) {
            printf "%-2s %-12s %d\n", i, abbrev[i], a[i]
        }
    }'
}
```

Then you can invoke the command just with `summary [option]`, where `[option]` accepts options to `squeue` if needed (mostly unnecessary).

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is awesome, thanks! quick question, do you have any idea how I might be able to define this entire things as an alias? like alias summary="<code you have>". It would be awesome to use it, thanks!

Comment: Good to hear it works well. BTW implementing lines of commands into an alias is a messy thing because of a lot of escapes. Instead we better to write it as a `function`, which makes us happier. Please take a look my additional answer. BR.

Comment: this is quite awesome! thanks, this is tremendously helpful. I am curious what the portion of your code `NR>1 {a[$5]++}` does, do you have any elaborations on that?

Comment: The code `NR>1 {a[$5]++}` means: "if the line number is greater than 1, then increment the value of the associative array `a` keyed with `$5`." The comparison with 1 is to skip the 1st header line. Otherwise the result will include `ST` (status) itself.

Answer (score 22):

I would interprete "quick command" differently. Additionally I would add -r for cases when you are using job arrays:

```
squeue -u <username> -h -t pending,running -r | wc -l
```

option -h removes the header "wc -l" (word count) counts the line of the output.
Eventually I am using it with watch

```
watch 'squeue -u <username> -h -t pending,running -r | wc -l'
```

Comment: To distinguish try: `squeue -u <username> -h -t pending,running -r -O "state" | uniq -c`

Answer (score 5):

This comment from @skytaker really provides the best solution in my view, distinguishing between pending and running, giving you a separate count for each. Only difference to Stefan Maschek's solution is the use of uniq as opposed to wc:

```
squeue -u <username> -h -t pending,running -r -O "state" | uniq -c
```

Comment: Also works:  `squeue -h -u $USER -o '%t' | uniq -c`

Answer (score 0):

**I prefer this way** you can display the job information at the end of the file which includes the running time

```
squeue -j $SLURM_JOBID
```

another way

you can put the time at the beginning and at the end then count by yourself

```
date
```

- for the end file time  (put `date` at the end of the file)

OR

you can display your all jobs which running now with their duration :
for all your jobs

```
squeue -u <Username>
```

[image]